# How to insert data at certain places in a python list for a specific problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git

I have a python list (as shown below) which contains two types of strings: One is like '1556294808 2019-04-26 21:36:48 +0530' and the other one is like '3 files changed, 126 insertions(+), 18 deletions(-)', but these are not strictly at alternate positions.

I want to have these two types of strings at alternate positions by inserting '0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)' in-between two strings of type one, in case they are at consecutive places. 
Element's order must not be changed.

```
['1556294808 2019-04-26 21:36:48 +0530', ' 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)', '1545318890 2018-12-20 20:44:50 +0530', '1545318858 2018-12-20 20:44:18 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 126 insertions(+), 18 deletions(-)', '1545208408 2018-12-19 14:03:28 +0530', '1545208369 2018-12-19 14:02:49 +0530', ' 2 files changed, 352 insertions(+), 12 deletions(-)', '1545134701 2018-12-18 17:35:01 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 134 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)', '1545116120 2018-12-18 12:25:20 +0530', '1545115969 2018-12-18 12:22:49 +0530', ' 2 files changed, 25 insertions(+), 17 deletions(-)', '1545114797 2018-12-18 12:03:17 +0530', '1545114768 2018-12-18 12:02:48 +0530', ' 2 files changed, 107 insertions(+), 17 deletions(-)', '1545107389 2018-12-18 09:59:49 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 55 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)', '1545051306 2018-12-17 18:25:06 +0530', '1545051282 2018-12-17 18:24:42 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 121 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)', '1545031219 2018-12-17 12:50:19 +0530', '1545031091 2018-12-17 12:48:11 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 327 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)', '1545027187 2018-12-17 11:43:07 +0530', '1545027168 2018-12-17 11:42:48 +0530', ' 2 files changed, 79 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)', '1545022804 2018-12-17 10:30:04 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 47 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)']
```

Comment: can you please add your expecting output.

Comment: @mtkilic the expected output is like this: ['1556294808 2019-04-26 21:36:48 +0530', ' 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)', '1545318890 2018-12-20 20:44:50 +0530', '0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)','1545318858 2018-12-20 20:44:18 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 126 insertions(+), 18 deletions(-)', '1545208408 2018-12-19 14:03:28 +0530','0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)', '1545208369 2018-12-19 14:02:49 +0530']

Comment: Humble request to community members, rather than decreasing the reputation of my questions, please suggest me how to ask a question or how to format one. I am new to this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve work for you. Below I am looping thru entire list to check if `+0530` because it looks like its in every timestamp. if you want you can write function to check if its timestamp, which will be more valid.

```
data = []
for i in range(len(y)):
  if "+0530" in y[i]:
    data.append(y[i])
    if "+0530" in y[i+1]:
      data.append("0 files changed, 0 insertions(+)")
  else:
    data.append(y[i])
```

Output of `data` :

```
1556294808 2019-04-26 21:36:48 +0530
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
1545318890 2018-12-20 20:44:50 +0530
0 files changed, 0 insertions(+)
1545318858 2018-12-20 20:44:18 +0530
 3 files changed, 126 insertions(+), 18 deletions(-)
```

Comment: The solution works fine for most of the lists, but for a list in which last entry is of the type '1556294808 2019-04-26 21:36:48 +0530', I am getting an error y[i + 1]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @jaspu update this part `for i in range(len(y)):` with `for i in range(len(y) -1 ):`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly the code below should work, it's basically looping through the list and if two contiguous 'date' strings are found it inserts a string in between. The loop is going backwards to avoid the referencing issue of inserting new elements.

```
import datetime as dt

items = ['1556294808 2019-04-26 21:36:48 +0530', ' 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)', '1545318890 2018-12-20 20:44:50 +0530', '1545318858 2018-12-20 20:44:18 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 126 insertions(+), 18 deletions(-)', '1545208408 2018-12-19 14:03:28 +0530', '1545208369 2018-12-19 14:02:49 +0530', ' 2 files changed, 352 insertions(+), 12 deletions(-)', '1545134701 2018-12-18 17:35:01 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 134 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)', '1545116120 2018-12-18 12:25:20 +0530', '1545115969 2018-12-18 12:22:49 +0530', ' 2 files changed, 25 insertions(+), 17 deletions(-)', '1545114797 2018-12-18 12:03:17 +0530', '1545114768 2018-12-18 12:02:48 +0530', ' 2 files changed, 107 insertions(+), 17 deletions(-)', '1545107389 2018-12-18 09:59:49 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 55 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)', '1545051306 2018-12-17 18:25:06 +0530', '1545051282 2018-12-17 18:24:42 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 121 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)', '1545031219 2018-12-17 12:50:19 +0530', '1545031091 2018-12-17 12:48:11 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 327 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)', '1545027187 2018-12-17 11:43:07 +0530', '1545027168 2018-12-17 11:42:48 +0530', ' 2 files changed, 79 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)', '1545022804 2018-12-17 10:30:04 +0530', ' 3 files changed, 47 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)']
new_item = ' 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)'

fmt = ['%Y %m %d','%H %M %S','%z']
def check_for_date(item, fmt):
    try:
        date = item.split()
        for i in range(3):
            dt.datetime.strptime(date[i+1].replace('-',' ').replace(':',' '), fmt[i])
        return True
    except ValueError as err:
        return False

for ii in range(len(items)-1,0,-1):
    if (check_for_date(items[ii], fmt)) and (check_for_date(items[ii-1], fmt)):
        items.insert(ii, new_item)
```